# nginx SSL connection fail

Tags: nginx, gerrit

i am having a issue trying to authenticate my account with github plugin and a reverse-proxy which is nginx, this is my configuration

Gerrit version: 2.14.8

```
$ cat /etc/nginx/sites-available/my_config_file
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name my_server_hostname;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate conf.d/certificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key conf.d/certificate.key;

    location ^~ / {
            proxy_pass        http://127.0.0.1:8081;
            proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header  Host $host;
    }
```

}

```
$ cat /var/log/nginx/error.log
018/08/15 08:49:47 [error] 3247#3247: *1 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: IP_ADDRESS, server: my_server_hostname, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://127.0.0.1:8081/", host: "my_server_hostname"
```

Gerrit log does not shows any error

I think that this is a very simple issue but i can not figure out how to fix it, please help me on this.
Thanks